# Transaction Scope and Multiple Regions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

Does transaction scope operate across multiple regions? If I have 2 Processes, one that opens a connection and transaction, performs a insert command then calls another process before the transaction is closed, Will the original transaction take into account if transaction 2 fails? Here is the example code below.

**Region 1:**

```
public static void process1()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connections.conn()))
    {
        //Open the connection
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            //Create A new Sql transaction.
            using (var trans = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
            {
               using (SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand
               {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                CommandText = sql,
                Connection = conn,
                CommandTimeout = 300
                })
                {                            
                    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            process2()
            trans.complete();
            }
         }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

**Region 2**

```
public static void process2()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connections.conn()))
    {
        //Open the connection
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            //Create A new Sql transaction.
            using (var trans2 = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
            {
               using (SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand
               {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                CommandText = sql,
                Connection = conn,
                CommandTimeout = 300
                })
                {                            
                    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            trans2.complete();
            }
         }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

In my application process 2 is dependant on process 1's success. If process 1 is successful and process 2 is not then the result of process 1 is useless.

I understand that when the commans execute in the same transaction block they will both fail if one does but as I coded my application to do it accorss different regions I was wondering if the same applied in this situation. I would rather not having to recode two different processes together.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: What do you mean by "Processes" and "Regions" here?  Are you talking about 2 different actual operating system processes (i.e. two different .exe files?)

Comment: I was wondering about the terminology myself. Basically 2 blocks of code in a c# code file

Comment: fyi: SQL Server nested transactions may not behave the way you expect. See [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) for some discussion.

Comment: Hmm looks like nesting transactions could cause more hastle then they are work if it comes to the point where I need to perform some data recovery. Just reading that article makes me worry abou the complexity

Comment: The example code for [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indicates that the SQL connection is associated with the transaction when you open the connection. Since you open the connection before creating the transaction scope, you may not be getting the benefits of the transaction. I haven't found anything explicit that clarifies the issue of how the magic occurs when using TransactionScope. FWIW, I've always used SQLTransaction and included code in sprocs to check for an existing transaction before starting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just two blocks of code within a single C# file, then to make sure either both processes happen or neither happen, you would want to wrap your call to those functions in a transaction scope as well.  Like so:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope()) {
     process1();
     process2();
     tx.Complete();
}
```

This way if either process1 or process2 fails, both will be rolled back.

Comment: Ok So that is similar to how my appliction works. I'll try force an error on it. If Process1 Still works then I'll recode it to fit your example.

Comment: Hmm. The first transaction executed despite the fact I forced the second one to fail..